# Compute the following sum in terms of an expression having only one binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

Compute the following sum in terms of an expression having only one binomial coefficient: For $m,n \in\mathbb{N}$

$$\sum_{k\leq m}(-1)^k {n\choose k}$$

I have started with

$$\sum_{k\leq m}(-1)^k {n\choose k} = \sum_{k\leq m}(-1)^k  \frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

But I am having trouble proceeding from there! I feel as if I am doing something wrong and am not able to find any results that could help. If I could get any hints that would be ideal! Thank you!